# FileManager changes are not working for reordering and has ErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm completely new to iOS developing and Swift.

I want to implement edit mode for my table view which shows a list of files like the image below:

[image: how my table view displays]

Everything works fine in edit mode, and my codes works fine in deletion, but when I change the place of my files by dragging them, they will come back to their first place each time. The code for changing the file manager wold not run and it has this error:

> NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0249c90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}`

This line will not call:

```
 do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: (documentURL?.path)!, toPath: (documentURL_Dest?.path)!)
    }
```

In here, this is my `moveRowAt` function in the view controller:

```
    var documents = [PDFDocument]()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let movedObject = self.documents[sourceIndexPath.row]

    let document = movedObject
    let documentURL = document.documentURL
    let document_Dest = documents[destinationIndexPath.row]
    let documentURL_Dest = document_Dest.documentURL




    documents.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

    documents.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    //this do wouldn't call and catch is calling each time
    do {


        try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: (documentURL?.path)!, toPath: (documentURL_Dest?.path)!)


    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Error in copying Data.plist: \(error)") // see the above quoted error message from here
    }


    refreshData()

}
```

and here is my `refreshData()` function:

```
 private func refreshData() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    documents = contents.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0) }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

@objc func documentDirectoryDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    refreshData()
}
```

I put this line code for enabling edit mode in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory, `FileManager` doesn't let you move a file to a folder where a file with **the same name** already exists.

You shouldn't load the files again if you want to change the files' **order** in your list, since that will reset the original order.

If you are not planning to show more than one folder in your file or you don't want to add a function to move files to another location, you should remove this whole chunk of your code:

```
do {
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: (documentURL?.path)!, toPath: (documentURL_Dest?.path)!)
} catch let error {
    NSLog("Error in copying Data.plist: \(error)") // see the above quoted error message from here
}


refreshData()
```

Otherwise, you should handle the error accordingly (for e.g. show an alert to let the user that a file already exists with the same name in that directory).

Comment: thank you very very much for your help. thats right and I do not need two copy of my files in the folder, I just need to  find a solution to make reordering documents works correctly, now my problem is that when I change the place of my items in list and then close the app and run it again whole changes reset back to its default. it happens each time refreshData runs. can you suggest me any solution or tutorial? Appreciate

Comment: You should save the order inside `UserDefaults` or a database of some kind. Read more about that [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults).

Comment: thank you very much I read the page you recommend. very helpful but Im new to swift and confused. I need a little more help. is it possible to update and tell me some codes of NsUserDefaults if possible. Appreciate ,